# How can I load multi resouece to resourceModuleURLs

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I use Flex3.0(SDK 3.2).

I have a question Flex(resourceModuleURLs).

I am making loading of the resource using flashVars properties in the HTML wrapper　as follows now.

```
AC_FL_RunContent(
    "src", "ResourceModuleApp",
    "flashVars", "resourceModuleURLs=es_ES_ResourceModule.swf&localeChain=es_ES",
    "width", "500",
    "height", "500",
    "align", "middle",
    "id", "ResourceModuleApp",
    "name", "ResourceModuleApp",
    "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
    "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
    "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
);
```

※Reference
 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3c.html

Although it is only es_ES_ResourceModule.swf now, I would like to specify two, es_ES_ResourceModule.swf and es_ES_ResourceModule2.swf.

Please let me know how it should write.

---

Thank you!

I try 「set it as a runtime shared library」.
However, this case was not able to be solved.

Why 「set it as a runtime shared library」Is it necessary to do?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and not the original Flex3 wrapper (this has been fixed in Flex 4 to use swfobject).

From here, you can only load *one* resource module at a time.  I don't see why you would ever need to have more than one as they are language specific.  If you want to load something else in there, you need to set it as a runtime shared library that needs to be loaded.